# Minimal nginx configuration to start it from the command line

Tags: nginx

I wish to just run `nginx` on the command line, in the foreground, as my own user, with configs and files to serve from the current directory.

What is the minimal configuration and CLI invocation that will start nginx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the following to be the minimal starting configuration that serves contents from the given `html` directory in the current `$PWD` directory:

Run

```bash
nginx -p $PWD -e stderr -c nginx.conf
```

with `nginx.conf` being:

```
# Run nginx using:
#     nginx -p $PWD -e stderr -c nginx.conf

daemon off;  # run in foreground

events {}

pid nginx.pid;

http {
    access_log /dev/stdout;

    # Directories nginx needs configured to start up.
    client_body_temp_path .;
    proxy_temp_path .;
    fastcgi_temp_path .;
    uwsgi_temp_path .;
    scgi_temp_path .;

    server {
        server_name   localhost;
        listen        127.0.0.1:1234;

        location / {
            root html;
        }
    }

}
```

I tested this with `nginx version: nginx/1.22.0`.

If you then create a file to serve, such as

```bash
mkdir html
echo hi > html/myfile
```

you can visit http://localhost:1234/myfile in the browser.

### Explanations

- You can see what the CLI flags do in `nginx -h`.
- `-e stderr` is used because otherwise nginx will try to use its default `error.log` location already for the purpose of pointing out errors in the config file.
- `-p $PWD` is used because nginx requires absolute paths for its prefix directory.
- When referring to a directory such as `client_body_temp_path .;` the `.` will effectively be the given `-p` prefix directory.