# Try to run react app on EC2 Amazon Linux with PM2

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vite, pm2

I try to run my app on EC2 Amazon Linux 2023, but even if it looks in pm2 logs that it runs (shows regular vite info that I can access it via localhost:5173). I cannot access it via "public-ip:5173". AWS CodeBuild Pipeline shows that everything went correct. Security group in inbounds rools is set like that:

| Port/Protokol | Source |
| --- | --- |
| 5173/Custom TCP | 0.0.0.0/0 |
| 80/HTTP | 0.0.0.0/0 |
| 80/HTTP | ::/0 |
| 443/HTTPS | 0.0.0.0/0 |

## My appspec.yml:

```
version: 0.0

os: linux 

 files:
 - source: /
   destination: /janus-ui
   overwrite: true

file_exists_behavior: OVERWRITE

permissions:
  - object: /
    pattern: "**"
    owner: ec2-user
    group: ec2-user

hooks:

  BeforeInstall:
    - location: scripts/before_install.sh
      timeout: 1600
      runas: root

  AfterInstall:
      - location: scripts/after_install.sh
        timeout: 1600
        runas: root

  ApplicationStart:
    - location: scripts/start_server.sh     
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
```

## My after_install.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

# navigate to app folder
cd /janus-ui

# install dependencies
npm install
npm install --save react react-dom react-scripts react-particles-js
npm install pm2 -g
```

## My before_install.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

# navigate to app folder
cd /janus-ui

# install node and npm
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | sudo -E bash -
yum -y install nodejs npm
```

## My start_server.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

# navigate to app folder
cd /janus-ui

pm2 start npm --name "janus-ui" -- run prod
pm2 startup
pm2 save
pm2 restart all
```

my scripts in package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "env-cmd -f .env.development vite --port 5173",
    "prod": "env-cmd -f .env.production vite --port 5173",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
```

## My buildspec.yml:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 18
   
    commands:
        # install npm
        - npm install
       
  build:
    commands:
        # run build script
        - npm run-script build
     
artifacts:
  # include all files required to run application
  # notably excluded is node_modules, as this will cause overwrite error on deploy
  files:
    - dist/**/*
    - src/**/*
    - package.json
    - appspec.yml
    - index.html
    - tsconfig.json
    - tsconfig.node.json
    - vite.config.ts
    - scripts/**/*
    - .env.production
```

Generally I stuck. I do it first time and I tried nginx, now pm2 looks easier, but still I cannot access even if logs looks like everything is correct.

I expect to see my page via browser on "public-ip:5173"

Comment: What are you using as server in the ec2? nginx, apache? Checking all your files, you are not using a server.

Comment: That’s a good point. I use Tomcat for backend (spring boot). But I didn’t configured anything for React. I thought PM2 is enough. Can I somehow link my react app with tomcat which is in Spring? Or something else would be better and easier option? Sorry for stupid questions, in devops I am newbie :-)

Comment: Use a tomcat for react it is like kill an ant with a nuke. Read this https://jrichardsz.github.io/web/how-serve-spa-csr-react-angular-vue-webs . I will answer with several options. How are you using that yaml files?

Comment: "I do it first time and I tried nginx, now pm2 looks easier" those are different things.  `pm2` is for managing server-side node applications.  React is a client side application framework.  So you need something like nginx to serve the resources to the browser.   Since its react there's no node stuff to run server side.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Summary

To run a react web application you need an http server. React comes with a tiny server just for development (npm run dev) but not for production (for real users) environments.

I will show you some options from manually to automated

### Advice

I advice you to use docker for your react and spring boot api. I can provide you ready to use templates. Also with this you will work like a pro.

You can install docker with the [official guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) or my [script](https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/cf8fcec5f652a0cca432120c15d8595f#file-docker_docker_compose_oneclick_install-v3-sh)

https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/cf8fcec5f652a0cca432120c15d8595f#file-docker_docker_compose_oneclick_install-v3-sh

### Ec2 port

Open the 80 port is not complicated

[image]

You can use another port if you need: 8080 for spring boot and 8081 for react

Then the aws public url is something like

http://ec2-aa-bb-cc-131.compute-1.amazonaws.com

[image]

> image source: https://mkyong.com/server/namecheap-domain-name-and-amazon-ec2/

If you chose the 80 port for react, you could use directly the aws public url

> thanks erick258 comment

### React build

No matter the option you choose, you will need to build the app before serve it. Usually `npm run build` does it. Check if the **build** folder has your web with javascript minified. Like:

[image]

If you are not able to build the web app (react, angular, vue, svelte, etc), you could not serve it in the ec2 server

### Apache

By default the 80 port is used by apache, so that matches with the 80 of your ec2.

Check these:

- http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-create-a-home-page-for-apache-server-in-linux.php
- https://medium.com/@purplejen/installing-the-apache-server-and-creating-a-sample-html-page-33b1938bf0b8
- https://access.redhat.com/solutions/67298
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-18-04

I think the easiest way is to wipe this folder /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/ and put your dist content. Then restart the apache

### Apache with docker

So easy. Just create this Dockerfile at the root of your react project:

```
FROM httpd:2.4
WORKDIR /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
COPY build/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
RUN chmod -R 755 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
```

Then run this is your shell

```
npm install
npm run build
docker build -t acme-web-container .
# wait some seconds
docker run -d --name acme-web -it --rm -p 80:80 acme-web-container
```

The web will be ready to use with the ec2 public domain

### Nginx

Exactly the same of apache but with other folders and commands. Read these:

- https://medium.com/@terminalsandcoffee/create-a-website-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-7e80a3d17d09
- [Minimal nginx configuration to start it from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73297124/minimal-nginx-configuration-to-start-it-from-the-command-line)

### Nginx with docker

Create a nginx.conf file with [this](https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/547c09a43a3c61b82c2d385af1de0e7c#nginxconf) content

```
FROM nginx:1.15.8-alpine

#config
copy ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

#web
copy build/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
RUN chown -R nginx:nginx /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

Then run this is your shell

```
npm install
npm run build
docker build -t acme-web-container .
# wait some seconds
docker run -d --name acme-web -it --rm -p 80:80 acme-web-container
```

The web will be ready to use with the ec2 public domain

### Tomcat

Basically you just need to configure a folder in the web.xml. Read:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3958848/3957754
- https://www.moreofless.co.uk/static-content-web-pages-images-tomcat-outside-war

As I told you, tomcat is for java. You could use it but in a real environments and or for easy management and scaling:

- web and api should be in different git repositories
- web and api should be deployed in different hosts, each one with custom configurations.

  - For example the server for react don't need java (tomcat). With apache/nginx/docker the web site can be very light to an easy horizontal scalling.
  - The api server(java) will need more ram (vertical scaling) or some java tuning

### Nodejs

If you like nodejs, you could use these options to server your spa

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/static-server

Also you can use my library which is able to serve any spa (react, angular, vue, etc)

https://github.com/usil/nodeboot-spa-server

### One spa build for all environments

In spring boot if you use environment variables, you can build the application just one time and then deploy it everywhere just changing the env variables. Example:

- localhost

  - database_host: 127.0.01
  - database_port: 3306
  - database_user: root
  - database_password: changeme
- production

  - database_host: 10.10.15.20 or some private ip
  - database_port: 3306
  - database_user: usr_foo
  - database_password: TwFrMMic+rin91BMhQOIY

This is for real or enterprise environments in which you need several environment for the same application like:

- localhost:8081
- acme-dev.com
- acme-test.com
- acme.com (for real users)

If you like that way, sadly in react is not possible. Read this to understand it : https://jrichardsz.github.io/devops/just-one-build-for-spas

In the spas (react, angular, vue) you need to build for each environment (dev, test, staging, uat, prod, etc) which is not devops suitable. To fix this read https://jrichardsz.github.io/web/how-serve-spa-csr-react-angular-vue-webs and or you can use again my library:

https://github.com/usil/nodeboot-spa-server

Read the [What is /settings.json ?](https://github.com/usil/nodeboot-spa-server?tab=readme-ov-file#what-is-settingsjson-) section

### React with docker

In this mode, all the react repository is docker driven, so you don't need to perform the `npm run build` before the `docker build ..`. With this your react application could be fully ported to kubernetes or some orchestrator. I like https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk

Also you open the possibility to use devops:

- git push to react repository
- perform only docker commands (without human)
- deploy (without human)

Basically your Dockerfile should be like this:

```
# build environment
FROM node:alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

# production environment
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

And finally the required commands will be

```
docker build -t acme-web-container .
docker run -d --name acme-web -it --rm -p 80:80 acme-web-container
```

More details here:

- https://gist.github.com/przbadu/929fc2b0d5d4cd78a5efe76d37f891b6

Comment: " you need an http server." They have Tomcat.  "By default ec2 has the 80 port opened. " no it doesn't.  You have to explicitly open it in the security group (some automation may handle this for you, but it's certainly not opened "by default" ).  "[Apache] is by default in almost all linux machines" only if you install it.

Comment: Can you elaborate an answer?

Comment: #1 @mateusz-janus if this helped to solve your question, please click the checkmark on the left to mark this as solved and/or the arrow up  to mark as useful for future readers :D  #2 What option worked for you?

Comment: @JRichardsz
Done! :-) Apache with Docker - the easiest way for me, without any configuration. Thank you very much for your help! It's my first app which I configure from end to end and I am complety newbie in devops things. If you want to see how I configured you can check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77987963/https-for-httpdapache-ec2-amazon-linux-2023 ,because of course I stuck in the next (and I hope last) step.