# HTTPS for HTTPD(Apache) EC2 Amazon Linux 2023

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, ssl, amazon-ec2, https

how can I issue TLS/SSL certificates and link them to Apache run on Docker? I tried with certbot, but the issue is that I use Docker and via "Certify Certification Manager" I cannot authorize my domain which is registered by AWS(Route53).
I use AWS Code Build to deploy application:

## Dockerfile

```
FROM httpd:2.4
WORKDIR /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
COPY dist/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
RUN chmod -R 755 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
```

## appspec.yml

```
# This is an appspec.yml template file for use with an EC2/On-Premises deployment in CodeDeploy.
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/app-spec-ref.html
version: 0.0

os: linux 

files:
  - source: /
    destination: /janus-ui
    overwrite: true

file_exists_behavior: OVERWRITE

permissions:
  - object: /
    pattern: "**"
    owner: ec2-user
    group: ec2-user

hooks:

  BeforeInstall:
    - location: scripts/before_install.sh
      timeout: 1600
      runas: root

  AfterInstall:
      - location: scripts/after_install.sh
        timeout: 1600
        runas: root

  ApplicationStart:
    - location: scripts/start_server.sh     
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
```

## start_server.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# navigate to app folder
cd /janus-ui

# Check if container already works
if sudo docker ps | grep -q acme-web; then
    echo "Container acme-web is running."
    
    # Stop container
    sudo docker stop acme-web
    echo "Container has been stopped"
else
    echo "Container isn't running."
fi

npm run build
docker build -t acme-web-container .
# Wait 60 seconds to allow container start
sleep 60
sudo systemctl start docker
docker run -d --name acme-web -it --rm -p 80:80 acme-web-container
```

I want to be able run my app on port 443.

Comment: Good news about docker is you can play in your localhost. I advice to use a manual self signed certifed, add it in your dockerfile and run in the 443 port. Then try if in your browser, you can access to: https://localhost   To do it, read the step 2 and 3 of this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: You should be able to use the [Route53 plugin for certbot](https://certbot-dns-route53.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it changing Dockerfile

```
FROM httpd:2.4
WORKDIR /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
RUN chmod -R 755 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
RUN chmod -R 755 /usr/local/apache2/conf/
RUN chmod -R 755 /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
COPY dist/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
COPY certs/ /usr/local/apache2/conf/
RUN sed -i \
        -e 's/^#\(Include .*httpd-ssl.conf\)/\1/' \
        -e 's/^#\(LoadModule .*mod_ssl.so\)/\1/' \
        -e 's/^#\(LoadModule .*mod_socache_shmcb.so\)/\1/' \
        -e '/<VirtualHost _default_:80>/a \
           Redirect permanent / https://my-domain.com/' \
        /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

And docker run to:

```
docker run -d --name acme-web -it --rm -p 80:80 -p 443:443 acme-web-container
```